# twitter Bootstrap Popovers (and bootstrap in general) not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I realize this question has been asked multiple times before, but unfortunately, I am unable to find a solution from the existing questions & answers. I have created an html file which I think will have bootstrap functionality by linking to the CDN. It has a link to the JQuery CDN as well.

Well ... I just noticed that the Bootstrap styles are not loading at all. I am not sure why.

Nonetheless, I am assuming that fix will be relatively minor, but I have been struggling for much longer than that to figure out why the Popover is not working.

Please, if you are answering, make sure you are referencing the Bootstrap **3** rules.

*note: the structure of the below code was taken straight from the Bootstrap website.*

Without further ado !

Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" rel="popover" data-content="output" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click">1</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" rel="popover" data-content="output" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click">2</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" rel="popover" data-content="output" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click">3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.btn').popover();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add http: to this link -

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So this is the answer:

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```